# How to make two separate equal width columns of text side by side without text flow?

Tags: templates, columns, parcolumns, sidebyside

First let me point out that I searched for an answer to the question but I only partial answers, but nothing complete. So if you already know where I can find my answer just point me in the direction and I will remove this thread.

I want to make a document with two columns, with each column separate. In other words, I have two separate columns in which I can type, without text flowing from one column to another. My desire is to use for this is to create sample translation documents with 'Source Language' on the left column and 'Target Language' on the right column. If there was also a way to align the paragraphs with the corresponding translated text, that would be great.

Is there ``proper'' way of achieving this? I looked for a template on Overleaf but found none with the exact specifications that I needed.

Thank you

Comment: `parcolumns` (which you have already tagged) `parallel`,  `reledpar` packages all have facilities in this area.

Comment: Yes, the #parcolumns tag appeared as I was typing. That was a good hint I'll keep searching. Thanks

Comment: I found the template I was looking for on Overleaf - Setting Parallel Texts with reledmac and reledpar https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/setting-parallel-texts-with-reledmac-and-reledpar/krvvxwdrmkcz#.WylxtlMvzdd